# Unperiodisation of $\log(|\sin(x/2)|)$

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

We know that $f(x) = \log(|\sin(x/2)|)$ is a $2\pi$ periodic function. Is there a well known function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (ideally decaying to zero at infinity) such that we can write $f$ as a periodisation of $g$, i.e.
$$
f(x) = c + \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}g(x+2\pi n)?
$$
for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
The closest I can seem to get is that
$$
f(x) = -\log(2) + \frac{1}{2}\log(x^2) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}}\log\left(\frac{(x+2\pi n)^2}{(2\pi n)^2}\right).
$$
which is not exactly the same. We also know that
$$
f(x) = -\log(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n},
$$
but again, there is a similar problem.

**Note:**
Following @ashepler's answer, I have added a preferred type for $g$, i.e. decaying to zero at infinity.

Comment: A silly answer, but continuous on the implicit domain of $f$: $$g(x) = 2^{-\lceil 2\pi |x| \rceil - 1} \log(|\sin(x/2)|)$$

Comment: @aschepler What is so silly about it?

Comment: @aschepler That's excellent. After having tried to play with the function on desmos, did you mean to say $g(x) = 2^{-\lceil\frac{x}{2\pi}\rceil - 1}\log(|\sin(x/2)|)$. Could I ask how you obtained it?

Comment: @aschepler I am wondering if there is a non-periodic function that gives the periodic $f$...

Comment: Yeah, that's better. And I had the absolute value because I missed the sum is over $\mathbb{N}$ not $\mathbb{Z}$. The function is not periodic. It's just fairly trivially related to the wanted function.

Comment: Wait, the sum over $\mathbb{N}$ won't make a periodic function.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, sorry. The sum was mean't to be over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many choices for $g$. I do not know if they qualify as "well-known".

**Strategy for generating $g$**

We present one particular way to create such a function $g$. It is not the only way to do so (see below for the general characterization of such functions). Let $\varphi$ be a [partition of the unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) function, that is a function that verifies:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\varphi(x+2\pi n) = 1\tag{1}$$
It's really easy to build such functions. You can use the indicator function of $(-\pi, \pi)$, a [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) or even $\text{sinc}\left( \frac{x}{\pi}\right)$. You can also use any bump function $b(x)$ that doesn't vanish (e.g. a Gaussian) and build
$$\varphi(x) = \frac{b(x)}{\sum_{n
\in\mathbb Z}b(x+2\pi n)}$$

Then define $g$ of the following form:
$$g(x)=\varphi(x)(f(x)-c)$$
Then it is easy to check that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}g(x+2\pi n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\varphi(x+2\pi n)(f(x+2\pi n)-c)=f(x)\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\varphi(x+2\pi n)-c=f(x)-c$$
which gives you a solution. Note that I'm not sure if you really need any $c$, since you can always subtract it from $f$ and retain a periodic function (which is all you need).

Note also that this method allows you to build a solution $g$ that's arbitrarily smooth or with arbitrary decay at infinity.

**Characterization of the general solutions**

Let's try to identify the set of [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) $g$ that satisfy
$$f(x) = c + \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}g(x+2\pi n)\tag{2}$$
Taking the Fourier transform:
$$\begin{split}
\hat f(\xi) &=c\delta(\xi) + \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \hat g(\xi)e^{4i\pi^2 \xi n}\\
&=c\delta(\xi) + \hat g(\xi)\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{4i\pi^2 \xi n}\\
&=c\delta(\xi) + \hat g(\xi)\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \delta\left(\xi-\frac n{2\pi}\right)\\
&=c\delta(\xi) + \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \hat g\left(\frac n{2\pi}\right)\delta\left(\xi-\frac n{2\pi}\right)\\
\end{split}$$
where we have used the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Forms_of_the_equation) to turn the sum of complex exponentials into a Dirac comb. We have also assumed that $\hat g$ is  continuous at the multiples of $\frac 1 {2\pi}$, so that it is well-defined at those points. This is reasonable given that OP asked for $g$ to decay at infinity, so provided the decay is fast enough, continuity will be ensured.

On the other hand, as OP notes, $$f(x) = -\log(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\tag{3}$$
Taking, again, the Fourier transform:
$$
\hat f(\xi) = -\log(2)\delta(\xi)-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1 {2n}\left(\delta\left(\xi-\frac{n}{2\pi}\right)+\delta\left(\xi+\frac n {2\pi}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$
Identifying $(2)$ with $(4)$ yields the following charaterization of the set of solutions:
$$\boxed{\left\{
\begin{split}
c+\hat g(0)=-\log 2\\
\hat g(n)=-\frac 1 {2|n|} & \text{ if } n\neq 0
\end{split}
\right.}\tag{5}$$

Conversely, if a tempered distribution $g$ verifies the equations above, then it can be periodized into $f$ according to $(2)$. This characterizes the solutions $g$ to the problem. As we said, it assumes that such $\hat g$ is a continuous function at the non-zero integers.

It is clear that there are an infinite number of solutions, since only $(5)$ only constrains the behavior on a discrete grid of points.

**Final discussion**

I initially considered the inverse Fourier transform of $\xi\mapsto -\frac 1 {2\pi}\frac 1 {2|\xi|}$ as a solution. Unfortunately, in that case $g(x)=\alpha\log|x|+\beta \delta(x)$, and doesn't decay at infinity.

Instead, observing that the constraints $(5)$ are only on the behavior of $\hat g$ at the multiples of $\frac 1 {2\pi}$, I looked for solutions $\hat g$ in the form of
$$\hat g(\xi)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat g\left(\frac n{2\pi}\right)\hat\varphi\left(\xi-\frac n{2\pi}\right)=-(c+\log 2)\hat\varphi(\xi) -\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac 1 {2|n|}\hat\varphi\left(\xi-\frac n{2\pi}\right)$$ for a function $\hat \varphi$ that verifies:
$$\hat\varphi\left(\frac n {2\pi}\right) =\delta_{n=0} \text{ Kronecker symbol}\tag{6}$$
Then I realized that this condition $(6)$ is equivalent to the partition of the unity $(1)$.

Finally, note that the approach proposed in this post doesn't assume anything on the form of $f$, only that it's periodic (you could use different Fourier coefficients in $(4)$ and obtain the corresponding characterization $(5)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. Yes, I have come to realise that there are an infinite number of such periodisations. Thank you for the worked example, it is much appreciated. Also, apologies for the late reply, I only just noticed your answer.